# Reading all the .tar.gz files from a webpage into R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to read all the data from [this](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/archive/csv/) webpage into an R dataframe. I have the code to read the first file:

```
fn <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/archive/csv/1901.tar.gz"
download.file(fn,destfile="tmp.tar.gz")
file_names <- untar("tmp.tar.gz",list=TRUE) 

ISDGlobalHourlyData <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

but it's too time-consuming to do this individually for each one. Is there a way to read them all with one function?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the files in https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/archive/csv/ are quite large (>4Gb) so you may need to increase the seconds before the connection times out and it's probably a good idea to delete tmp.tar.gz and the csv files after they've been loaded into R, but it's up to you.

Also, before you run this, the `dir_ls()` command searches for all .csv files in your working directory named 'digits'.csv (e.g. "02960099999.csv"); if you have other .csv files with the same naming scheme, you may have to alter the regex accordingly (e.g. 'x number of digits'.csv).

Here is one approach that might be suitable:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

options(timeout = 3600)

# For this demo, the 'dates_of_interest' are the years 1901-1906
# For the 'real' command, change this to "1901:2022" (or whatever)
dates_of_interest <- 1901:1906

ISDGlobalHourlyData <- list()

for (i in seq_along(dates_of_interest)) {
  fn <- paste0("https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/archive/csv/",
               dates_of_interest[i],
               ".tar.gz")
  download.file(fn, destfile = "tmp.tar.gz")
  untar("tmp.tar.gz")
  filelist <- dir_ls(regexp = "\\d+\\.csv")
  ISDGlobalHourlyData[[i]] <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows,
                                      lapply(filelist, read.csv))
  # If you want to keep the files, delete these two lines:
  file.remove("tmp.tar.gz")
  file.remove(filelist)
}

names(ISDGlobalHourlyData) <- dates_of_interest
combined_ISDGlobalHourlyData <- bind_rows(ISDGlobalHourlyData, .id = "Year")

str(combined_ISDGlobalHourlyData)
#> 'data.frame':    38301 obs. of  20 variables:
#>  $ Year           : chr  "1901" "1901" "1901" "1901" ...
#>  $ STATION        : num  2.91e+09 2.91e+09 2.91e+09 2.91e+09 2.91e+09 ...
#>  $ DATE           : chr  "1901-01-01T06:00:00" "1901-01-01T13:00:00" "1901-01-01T20:00:00" "1901-01-02T06:00:00" ...
#>  $ SOURCE         : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ LATITUDE       : num  64.3 64.3 64.3 64.3 64.3 ...
#>  $ LONGITUDE      : num  23.4 23.4 23.4 23.4 23.4 ...
#>  $ ELEVATION      : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
#>  $ NAME           : chr  "KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI" "KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI" "KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI" "KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI" ...
#>  $ REPORT_TYPE    : chr  "FM-12" "FM-12" "FM-12" "FM-12" ...
#>  $ CALL_SIGN      : int  99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 ...
#>  $ QUALITY_CONTROL: chr  "V020" "V020" "V020" "V020" ...
#>  $ WND            : chr  "270,1,N,0159,1" "290,1,N,0082,1" "999,1,C,0000,1" "180,1,N,0082,1" ...
#>  $ CIG            : chr  "99999,9,9,N" "99999,9,9,N" "99999,9,9,N" "99999,9,9,N" ...
#>  $ VIS            : chr  "000000,1,N,9" "000000,1,N,9" "000000,1,N,9" "000000,1,N,9" ...
#>  $ TMP            : chr  "-0078,1" "-0072,1" "-0094,1" "-0061,1" ...
#>  $ DEW            : chr  "+9999,9" "+9999,9" "+9999,9" "+9999,9" ...
#>  $ SLP            : chr  "10200,1" "10200,1" "10200,1" "10183,1" ...
#>  $ GF1            : chr  "08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9" "04,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9" "08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9" "08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9" ...
#>  $ MW1            : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ EQD            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
head(combined_ISDGlobalHourlyData)
#>   Year    STATION                DATE SOURCE LATITUDE LONGITUDE ELEVATION
#> 1 1901 2907099999 1901-01-01T06:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#> 2 1901 2907099999 1901-01-01T13:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#> 3 1901 2907099999 1901-01-01T20:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#> 4 1901 2907099999 1901-01-02T06:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#> 5 1901 2907099999 1901-01-02T13:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#> 6 1901 2907099999 1901-01-02T20:00:00      4 64.33333     23.45         5
#>                     NAME REPORT_TYPE CALL_SIGN QUALITY_CONTROL            WND
#> 1 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 270,1,N,0159,1
#> 2 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 290,1,N,0082,1
#> 3 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 999,1,C,0000,1
#> 4 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 180,1,N,0082,1
#> 5 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 180,1,N,0098,1
#> 6 KALAJOKI ULKOKALLA, FI       FM-12     99999            V020 180,1,N,0098,1
#>           CIG          VIS     TMP     DEW     SLP
#> 1 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0078,1 +9999,9 10200,1
#> 2 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0072,1 +9999,9 10200,1
#> 3 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0094,1 +9999,9 10200,1
#> 4 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0061,1 +9999,9 10183,1
#> 5 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0056,1 +9999,9 10176,1
#> 6 99999,9,9,N 000000,1,N,9 -0028,1 +9999,9 10175,1
#>                                   GF1 MW1  EQD
#> 1 08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
#> 2 04,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
#> 3 08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
#> 4 08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
#> 5 08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
#> 6 08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>